# Is using Firestore Cloud functions different from using active listeners within the application?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, fetch

I've been trying to get an answer to my issue for weeks now without any luck.

I have an app in swift that displays a few labels on the screen. **I want the label text to change everyday at midnight, and I want to be able to decide what the label should say from my machine.**

I've been told to use either active listeners or cloud functions.

The video below shows a dev using firebase cloud functions to alter text in real time on an app.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z87OZtIYC_0

How is this any different from active listeners which also do the same?

Objectively speaking, what suits my use case more?

Comment: Cloud Functions runs code on Google backend servers.  Listeners run on the client mobile app.  They're completely different, so I'm not sure what you're trying to compare.

Comment: @DougStevenson, sorry for not being clear, I'm very new to coding. 
Im just trying to figure out what would be the most cost-effective and the most appropriate solution for achieving my purpose, which is in bold in the main question.
Thank you for replying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a function at midnight to make a UI change first requires that the app is open. If the app isn't even open then there isn't a UI to update. Therefore, there is no sense in tasking the server with this function because the app may not even be open. And the task of updating the UI should be the responsibility of the client, anyway.

Therefore, create a timer on the client (in your app) that makes a call every midnight to get data from the server that populates the labels. What you need is to create a `Timer` object that fires in `n` seconds to midnight that has an interval of 1 day that repeats infinitely. It may look something like this:

```
var midnightTimer: Timer?

midnightTimer = Timer(fire: Date().addingTimeInterval(secondsToMidnight), interval: oneDayInSeconds, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    self.updateLabels()
}

RunLoop.main.add(midnightTimer!, forMode: .common)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this, I've been looking for exactly this explanation for a while now!
(Will delete later to clean up the thread)